# PDO Insert not working

Tags: php, pdo, ckeditor

I have this form connected with ajax script, when i submit long texts the results does not saving in database(on posts table, i have post_content column as "longtext" type).When i submit something simple(like "hello world") the results saving correctly. When i used to use mysqli , i had solved the issue with this line of code(using mysqli_real_escape_string ):

```
//$insert_posts = "INSERT INTO posts (post_content,post_date,post_topic,post_by_uid) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['val'])."',NOW(),$id,'".$_SESSION['uid']."')";
```

But now with PDO, i can't. I tried this : `$conn->quote($reply)` but it doesn't worked.

```js
<script>
function saveEditorTrigger()
{
  for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ) CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
</script>
 <script>
   $(function () {
  
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  saveEditorTrigger();
  var str = CKEDITOR.instances['reply-post'].getData();
         var id = <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>;
  e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data:{ val : str, id : id },
            success: function (data) {
             alert('Your answer is submitted');
            location.replace("topic.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>");
   }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
```

```html
<form id="form" >
      <br>
      <textarea name="reply-post"></textarea>
      <script>
      CKEDITOR.replace( "reply-post" );
            </script>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">  
    </form>
```

The post.php file:

```html
<?php
include 'dbh.php'; 
session_start();
$reply = $_POST['val'];
$id = $_POST['id'] ;
$insert_posts = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post_content,post_date,post_topic,post_by_uid) VALUES ('".$reply."',NOW(),$id,'".$_SESSION['uid']."')");
//$insert_posts = "INSERT INTO posts (post_content,post_date,post_topic,post_by_uid) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['val'])."',NOW(),$id,'".$_SESSION['uid']."')";
$insert_posts -> execute();

?>
```

My question is what am i doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). You can also avoid potential SQL Injections attacks too! PDO, [is really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: well, for starters... You are not using PDO properly. The whole point of PDO is to not put values that you are inserting into your query and pass them as an array into your inserting object.

Comment: Your code is *wide open* to SQL injection.  When you check for errors, the database is *probably* telling you about a syntax error.  Correct the SQL injection problem and this problem likely becomes moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php'; 
session_start();
$reply = $_POST['val'];
$id = $_POST['id'] ;
$userId=$_SESSION['uid'];
$insert_posts = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO posts 
                (post_content,post_date,post_topic,post_by_uid) 
                VALUES 
                (:post_content,:post_date,:post_topic,:post_by_uid)");
            $insert_posts->bindParam(':post_content', $reply, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert_posts->bindParam(':post_date', NOW(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert_posts->bindParam(':post_topic', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert_posts->bindParam(':post_by_uid', $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert_posts -> execute();
?>
```

https://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html might be a good resource to learn

Comment: Your code is looking good, but is not working at all....no records on database,even with simple text "hello world".The only i get is "Your answer is submitted".

Comment: try adding static data first instead of getting values from form, $reply="Hello"; and run the script

Comment: there might be something, can i see your table structure

Comment: Post Table : (post_id  :int(8),post_content: longtext, post_date:datetime,post_topic: int(8), post_by_uid: varchar(255) ,votes: int(100) ) , post_id is AUTO_INCREMENT and is primary id

Comment: Sorry, no results again.

Comment: The problem was on NOW() . Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting this code, i make it worked.

```html
<?php
include 'dbh.php'; 
session_start();
$reply = $_POST['val'];
$id = $_POST['id'] ;
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
$user=$_SESSION['uid'];

$insert_posts = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post_content,post_date,post_topic,post_by_uid) VALUES (:post_content,NOW(),:post_topic,:post_by_uid)");
            $insert_posts->bindParam(':post_content', $reply);
            $insert_posts->bindParam(':post_topic', $id);
            $insert_posts->bindParam(':post_by_uid', $user);
            $insert_posts->execute();
}
?>
```